# Syntax (windows and linux) for multiple commands using Node cross-env

Tags: node.js, linux, windows, command-line, npm

I'm taking a look at a project that has this line in it's package.json to run Karma tests

```
 "scripts": {
        "test": "NODE_ENV=test karma start karma.conf.js",
```

This doesn't work in Windows when I try "npm test".

I gather this is because this is a *nix syntax. And, in fact, if I change it to

```
 "scripts": {
        "test": "set NODE_ENV=test && karma start karma.conf.js",
```

the tests start when I run npm test.

Looking around, the optimal solution appears to be to use the cross-env package and rewrite it like

```
 "scripts": {
        "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test && karma start karma.conf.js",
```

So I get the cross-env will take care of the "set NODE_ENV" part to work on multiple OSes, but it's the "&&" part I'm questioning.

Do I leave the "&&" between the commands when using cross-env? Will that work in windows and linux?

Comment: wouldn't have been faster to test this for  yourself, rather than get an answer from someone using a possibly different setup that confuses the issue? Seems like it should work, but you won't know for sure until you try it (IMHO). Good luck.

Comment: If I had access to a Linux shell now then yes. I'm on Windows, as I said in the question, it works on Windows. Will it work on Linux is the question.

Answer (score 5):

Your cross-env example won't work, it should just be:

```
 "scripts": {
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test karma start karma.conf.js",
```

without the `&&`. The command to run comes immediately after you're done setting the variables.

I found your question by searching for how to set multiple variables with cross-env and also how to run multiple scripts/commands with cross-env. So to address the "multiple commands" part of your question:

Given these 2 test scripts:

a.js

```
console.log('a', process.env.TEST_VAR, process.env.TEST_VAR_2);
```

b.js

```
console.log('b', process.env.TEST_VAR, process.env.TEST_VAR_2);
```

You'll find if you have an `&&` in the script in your package.json the subsequent scripts don't receive the variables. For example:

```
"scripts": {
    "check": "cross-env TEST_VAR=hello TEST_VAR_2=world node a.js && node b.js",
```

Running `npm run check` gives:

```
a hello world
b undefined undefined
```

You can solve this by having an extra script which runs the multiple commands and running that with cross-env:

```
"scripts": {
    "check": "cross-env TEST_VAR=hello TEST_VAR_2=world npm run check-real",
    "check-real": "node a.js && node b.js",
```

Now `npm run check` gives:

```
a hello world
b hello world
```

Comment: May I ask why i need to remove && ? I thought that chaining commands in Linux command line and in this case requiring the first execution to succeed to run the second command, needs && operator.

Comment: @GhassenBenHamida you're right normally, but in this case you're not chaining a command. `cross-env` is the only command being run and `karma start karma.conf.js` is essentially an argument being passed to cross-env. Internally `cross-env` will run the `karma...` command, or whatever else you passed to it.